# Getting user current status in laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel, maintenance-mode

I am using [this package](https://github.com/MisterPhilip/maintenance-mode) for maintenance but to define what user can have access to the site during down time and what user can't I have issue.

during passed few days I was searching and I read a lot, that because main controller loads after middleware it can't detect user status whether is login or not. (**I have no idea on that I just saw that repeatedly**)

#### Anyway here is the issue:

I want **allow** users with role of `Admin` access to the site in down time, And `visitors`, `other group of users` don't.

## What I did so far

based on package documentation I've made custome file in `App\Exemptions\AdminExemption.php` with this data:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exemptions;

use Auth; use Config; use App\User; use MisterPhilip\MaintenanceMode\Exemptions\MaintenanceModeExemption;

class AdminExemption extends MaintenanceModeExemption {
    public function isExempt()
    {

      if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'Admin') {
          return true;
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
        //if user is logged and it's admin show the site

        //if user is logged and isn't admin hide the site

        //if user isn't logged (is visitor) hide the site
    } }
```

I register this file in package config file `config\maintenancemode.php`

```
'exemptions' => [
        App\Exemptions\AdminExemption::class,
],
```

and replaced package class with laravel default in `Kernel`

```
protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \MisterPhilip\MaintenanceMode\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
//others...
]
```

## Issue

`Auth::check()` or `auth()->user()` or `Auth::user()` none of this can detect logged user and assume the user is not login (is visitor). So the website is shut for everyone even admins.

## Question

How can I get the real status of my current user in `AdminExemption.php` file?

**Status**

1. Is user (is admin) `show the site`
2. Is user (isn't admin) `don't show the site`
3. Is not user (visitor) `don't show the site`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've registered the middleware in the main middleware stack, which will occur before it gets to the middleware groups. You'll likely want to move the middleware lower down in the Kernel into the `web` middleware stack. This is because Laravel will only be aware of a logged in user if there is a session - and the session is only started in the web stack.

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

You'll need to place the middleware after the `StartSession` middleware - but you're probably best just to pop it on to the end there, and then the logged in status should be available in your middleware.

Comment: so you mean i move `\MisterPhilip\MaintenanceMode\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,` from `protected $middleware` to the bottom of `protected $middlewareGroups`?

Comment: Yes - but inside the `web` key. It's the `web` stack that starts the session and has any knowledge of an authenticated user.